# Django: How to generate data of a model from another model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two different models created for book and author,

```
class book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    GENDER = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female')
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
```

Is it possible to not use foreign key to link the two models, and generate authors automatically from book information(user input)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you should think about how to model your data efficiently. It probably makes more sense to have the `author` field in the `book` model be a foreign key to the `author` model.

Comment: what do you mean auto generate author ? You mean generate the class author using the information provided by the user from the book class

Comment: To create a ForeignKey is the most natural design for these two models. That's true regardless of whether you use django or not. BTW model names should start with an upper case letter (convention)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Django's [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save).

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def make_author(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Author.objects.create(name=instance.author)
```

That would create a new `Author` every time a new `Book` was created, using the `name` from the `Book.author` field.

Another way would be to overwrite the `Book.objects.create()` method on the `Book` model, and directly create an `Author` instance from inside the `Book` model. Advantage is that it would allow you to add more data directly when creating the (two) objects. Disadvantage is that it would make `Book` depend on the existence of `Author`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what im looking for :) appreciate it!